# custom shapes in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

i have drawn **chevron** using path concept by giving multiple coordinate(x,y) and one **rectangle** in the same **svg** container.how to add chevron in that rectangle as **single shape**?

```
 var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                      .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                      .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                     .interpolate("linear");

//The custom shape 
    var customshape = svgContainer.append("path")
                                .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
                                .attr("stroke", color)
                                .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                                .style("fill", color)
                                .style("opacity",0.6);
      //rectangle       
      var rectBox = svgContainer.append("rect")
                .attr("x",x_init)
                .attr("y",y_init)
                .attr("width",wid)
                .attr("height",hi)
                .attr("stroke-width",1)
                .attr("stroke","none")
                .attr("fill",rec_color)
                .style("opacity",0.9);
```

Comment: How does the "lineData" look like?

Comment: Could you add a JSFiddle?

Comment: I have the same question as @user2570560